# make a HTTP Request from React-Redux from localhost

Tags: httprequest, react-redux, redux-saga, web-development-server

I am new to React Redux, and All I already did:

1) activate my backend server (localhost:5000)

2) activate my front-end server using npm start (localhost:8080)

3) I tried to dispatch action by using

`this.props.dispatch({type: ActionTypes.FILE_UPLOAD_REQUEST, email: this.state.email, file: this.state.policyFile});`

4) Using atlas-saga, and call my service function associated with the dispatch :

`let result = yield call(Atlas.uploadFile, action.email, action.file);`

5) define the function as :

`` export const uploadFile = (email, file) => {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/v1/files/${email}/policies`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{} ,
        body: {'file': file}
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
} ``

After I try to run a function at my react( a function that calls the dispatch), it gives me errors that they cannot found the route. This is the error message from the console.

`Fetch API cannot load https://api-staging.autoarmour.co/v1/files/fakeemail@gmail.com/policies. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Yes, I did not create any reducer, just pure function that will upload a file. Thank you

Comment: i think problem is the server https://api-staging.autoarmour.co not accept a request from 'http://localhost:8080'.

Comment: Thanks bro, I will wait for other solutions

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present for more details about this issue

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVE IT, WOHOO!!!
The error message means that its not connected at the backend side at all. You need to make sure that it is connected. I solve it by connecting my redux to my react component. Thanks guys

Cheers!