# Can not send body in post request from Frontend to backend ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm making image uploader,BE side works fine I tested route in the `postman` and it uploaded the img as its supposed to do.

Route itself

```
app.post('/upload/:id',(req,res) => {
upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('--------err', err);
    } else {
        if (req.file === undefined) {
            res.json({
                msg:"Error:No file selected"
            })
        } else {
            console.log('--------req.file', req.file);
            Users.update({
                avatar : req.body.avatar
            },
                {where : {
                    id  : req.params.id
                    }})
            res.json({
                msg : "File uploaded",
                file : `uploads/${req.file.filename}`
            })
        }
    }
})
})
//Uploads
```

This is place where Pictures must be saved(Local folder)

```
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination : './uploads',
        filename : (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null,file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + ".jpeg" +
            path.extname(file.originalname));
        }
    })

// Init upload

const upload = multer({
    storage : storage,
    fileFilter : (req,file,cb) => {
        checkFileType(file,cb)
    }
}).single('avatar')

// Check file type
```

This function checks type of file

```
 const checkFileType = (file,cb) => {
        // Allowed extensions
        const fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
        //Check extensions
        const extname = fileTypes.test( path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase())
        //Check mimeType
        const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype)
    
        if(mimetype && extname) {
            return cb(null,true);
        } else {
            return cb("Error: Images Only")
        }
    
    }
```

As I said in the start in `postman` this route works just perfectly,But the Frontend is the main problem.

Here is how I'm sending request from the ReactJS Component

```
    const fileselectedHandler = (event: any): void => {
    newImg(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]))
  }

  const fileuploadHandler = () : void => {
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('avatar', img)
    axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/upload/${match.params.userId}`,{
      avatar : data
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(err =>
        console.log('--------err', err)
      )
  }
```

`<input name='avatar' onChange={fileselectedHandler} type={'file'}/> <button onClick={fileuploadHandler}>Upload Picture</button>`

Problem is whenever I hit `Upload picture` button request is being sent but the response is like this `data: {msg: "Error:No file selected"}` and in the body which is sending is this `data: "{"avatar":{}}"`. Any suggestions why is this happening and how to fix it ?

Comment: In the request you're making from the front-end, how are you setting the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`? Multter will not process any request which is not multipart.

Comment: O wait i did not know that I ll try that rn

Comment: Still got the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload files using React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233585/how-to-upload-files-using-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not making a multipart request form the front-end (`Content-Type`
header should be `multipart/form-data`, see first note on [npm page of multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer))

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42096508/6718353), take a look at the `fileUpload` function in the code which makes use of the [FormData web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) (WARNING: may run into compatibility issues with Internet Explorer).

See if this helps.