# How to pass array of object which contain file also in a formdata & how back end received those

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, form-data

Currently, I'm trying to pass an array of objects which also contains the file to BE but that's causing errors & backend not being able to receive those array payload keys showing unreadable [Object object],[Object object], view

I found an option to send all data using denote nesting but if I used denote nesting how could I be able to recombine that array back to its original view on the backend?

Comment: You are probably sending reference to instance of File API, not raw data. There are so many articles/threads about it. E.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46233585/how-to-upload-files-using-react)